# How to draw welded braid diagrams using braids package in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, braids

I want to draw welded braids (with virtual crossings/weldings) in LaTeX.

I am using the TikZ `braids` package to draw normal braids. But I don't know how to draw welded braids.

Notice the difference between a classical braid and a welded braid in the following picture:

[image]

The left one is a classical braid crossing, while the right one is a virtual crossing.

In a classical braid only the classical braid crossings are allowed, while in the case of welded braids both classical and virtual crossings are allowed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Your question is more likely to get an answer if you post a minimal document showing what you have done with the `braids` package and an image of what you would like to achieve.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: It would also help if you said what "welded braids" are!

Comment: Thank you for showing what "welded braids" are, but an example of what have you tried till now is still missing: http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/

Comment: When I tried the `braids` package, I got this warning: _Package braids Warning: This package was designed using PGF2.10; you are using 3.0.1a._ The `braids` package is too old!

Comment: @PaulGaborit When `braids` was written, PGF2.10 was the beta version so that was a warning for those who were still on 2.00 that it might not work with their version!  I agree that it looks a bit out of date now.  In fact, it's probably time that `braids` got a bit of attention.  Probably time to `LaTeX3`-ify it.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using the version of `braids` available from [github](https://github.com/loopspace/braids).  That introduces a bit more customisation, in particular the ability to specify the `gap` in the under-strand.  By setting `gap=0` you can erase it altogether.  This can be set during the path so you can switch between virtual and classical crossings.  You can even have virtual and classical crossings on the same level.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{braids}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\braid[gap=0] a_1-[braid/gap=.1]a_3 [braid/gap=0] a_2;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that the *first* optional argument doesn't need the `braid` prefix, but any later ones do.

The above produces:

[image: Braid with virtual crossings]