# Tikzcd - Modified String Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

[image]

I can't seem to find a general tikz-cd outline for creating the above diagram.  My use case is for parametric lenses in category theory, but I can't seem to find any code even close to the above diagram.  Can anyone help with providing code using the tikz-cd package which produces the above diagram?

Comment: This “string diagrams” are not possible with `tikz-cd`. Maybe a starting point is in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418241)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely easier to do with pure `TikZ` instead of `tikz-cd`. The node layout isn't hard with `tikz-cd`, but the line shapes, specifically the splitting, curved paths, are quite difficult. Much easier with `Tikz`.

The basic idea is to place your nodes and then draw the lines between them. Play around with the positioning until it looks the way you want. I made two styles of nodes (`big box` and `small box`). Many adjustments are possible.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{big box/.style={draw, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=4cm},
    small box/.style={draw, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[big box] at (0,0)(F){};
\node[right=of F](M){};
\node[above=of M.center, anchor=center](B1){$B$};
\node[below=of M.center, anchor=center, yshift=-.5cm](B2){$B'$};
\node[big box, right=of M] (G){};
\node[small box, above=of F.center, anchor=center](F1){$f$};
\node[small box, below=of F.center, anchor=center](F2){$f^*$};
\node[small box, above=of G.center, anchor=center](G1){$g$};
\node[small box, below=of G.center, anchor=center](G2){$g^*$};
\node[left=of F.west, yshift=.5cm](A1){$A$};
\node[left=of F.west, yshift=-1cm](A2){$A'$};
\node[right=of G.east, yshift=1cm](C1){$C$};
\node[right=of G.east, yshift=-1.25cm](C2){$C'$};
%
\draw[->](C2)--(C2-|G2.east);
\draw[->](G2)--(G2-|B2.north east)to[out=180,in=0](B2.north west);
\draw[->](B2.north west)--(B2.north west-|F2.east);
\draw[->](F2)--(A2);
\draw[->](A1)--++(2,0)to[out=0,in=180]++(1,.5)--(F1);
\draw[->](A1)--++(2,0)to[out=0,in=180]++(1,-.5)--(F.center);
\draw[->](F.center)--++(1,0)arc(90:-90:.4)node(T){}--(T-|F2.east);
\draw[->](F1)--++(3,0)node(T2){};
\draw[->](T2.center)to[out=0,in=180]++(1,-.5)--++(1,0)node(T3){}to[out=0,in=180]++(1,.5)--(G1);
\draw[->](T3){}to[out=0,in=180]++(1,-.5)--(G.center)--++(1,0)arc(90:-90:.4)node(T4){}--(T4-|G2.east);
\draw[->](G1)--(C1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```