# Tikz Braids: How to draw Singular Braids (intersections)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, braids

I've been using the TikZ braids package, which works great. Unfortunately, I now need to start drawing singular braids/knots, which I don't think the package handles. These concepts are "less popular" than regular braids/knots so it is understandable that it hasn't been developed.

Here's a basic example I pulled off. The first crossing, illustrated with a black dot, is the **singular crossing**. These are typically denoted with a black dot. The other crossings are completely normal.

[image]

**My attempt:**

My method to draw the singular crossing isn't great because

1. I had to manually draw a black circle
2. I had to guess the intersection position until I got it correctly

In short, this method is sort of a time-waster; but I'm going to have to draw lots of these...

**My questions:**
Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on a more systematic way of doing this? Perhaps a way to access a list of intersections (which I assume the package computes behind the scenes) which I could use to my advantage? I try to look for ways to avoid wasting time before I give up and accept wasting time.

Ideally, the package could be extended so that whenever a user types `t_1`, for example, instead of `s_1`, it detects that the user would like a singular crossing, so that it does all that guesswork/drawing for me. But obviously I'm completely incapable of doing that myself.

**My code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{braids} 

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \def\height{3.5} %bar lengths
    \def\width{3.2} %bar difference heights, .2 added to make it nicer
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic[braid/.cd, 
        number of strands = 3,
        thick]
        {braid={ s_1, s_2[braid/gap=0], s_3}};
        \filldraw (0.5,-0.75) circle (0.07cm); %the singular intersection
        \draw[thick] (-0.2,0) -- (\width,0);   %top bar
        \draw[thick] (-0.2,-\height) -- (\width,-\height); %bottom bar
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \emph{$\tau_1\sigma_2\sigma_3$}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/385601/86

Comment: Also, in terms of locating the crossing, there are coordinates scattered all over the braid.  The crossings are exactly half way between where a strand enters and leaves each level so very easy to get to using the calc library.

Comment: Also, can you please use full MWEs in your questions.  It's tricky figuring out what the preamble should be.  (See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/86 for example)

Comment: Oh my bad, I added the preamble. Also, I did see that other post and will definitely use it since it will help me deal with gaps that might be too big to cover with my black circle. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `knots` package has more advanced options but a very blunt way to marking the crossing is to recover it via intersections of lines connecting the marks on the strands. Note also that, by using a local bounding box, you can avoid the hard coded dimensions for the horizontal bars.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{braids,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic[local bounding box=my braid,braid/.cd, 
    number of strands = 3,
    thick,
    name prefix=braid]
    {braid={ s_1, s_2, s_3}};
    \filldraw (intersection of braid-2-0--braid-2-1 and braid-1-0--braid-1-1) 
     circle[radius=0.07cm];
    \draw[thick] ([xshift=-1ex]my braid.north west) --  ([xshift=1ex]my braid.north east)
        ([xshift=-1ex]my braid.south west) --  ([xshift=1ex]my braid.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No need to use intersections.  There's plenty of coordinates scattered around a braid which can be used to find crossing points.

Comment: Looking closer, I see that effectively that's what you are doing by looking at the intersection of the straight lines between the coordinates.

Comment: There are coordinates at the start and end of the strands which could be used instead of the local bounding box coordinates.  (But these are all nit-picks.)

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thanks! Yes, as I wrote, it is a rather blunt way, and I certainly do not understand the library as well as you do. ;-) However, it seems to work and is reasonably simple. I also do not know if it is fool proof, but as long as the strands are symmetric around the crossing, it should work.

Comment: The concept behind the braids package was to deal with the cases where the braid was very systematic, and part of that is that the crossings are carefully located - that's how I can put the break in the under strand in the right place.  So without boxing myself in for future updates, I have no intention to introduce anything different.

Comment: I appreciate your help @Schrödinger's cat! Especially about the top and bottom bars. I will try to utilize Andrew's comments to make this more systematic :)